# What can you do with a moving knife besides cutting a cake?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, machine-models

In the [fair cake-cutting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_cake-cutting), two different computational models are used:

- A discrete model, in which the algorithm issues queries to the players and proceeds according to their replies;
- A continuous model, in which one or more "knives" move continuously over the cake under certain restrictions, until a player shouts "stop".

The continuous model is strictly stronger: there are problems that can be solved easily in the continuous model, but cannot be solved in finite time in the discrete model, e.g, [envy-free cake-cutting with connected pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envy-free#Connected_pieces).

So I wonder what other problems, besides cake-cutting, can benefit from a "moving knife" or a similar continuous model?

For example, is there a continuous variant of a Turing machine, that can easily solve problems that are unsolvable for a discrete Turing machine?

Comment: Well, this is a toplogical result, which belongs to a large family of pretty nice results (it is essentially a fixed point theorem). Among them is Kakatoni fixed point theorem, which implies the Nash equilibrium result. Matousek book on topology is a good point to start reading on this stuff (warning - its mathematically not easy stuff).
http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540003625